# Custom spacing between only some cells in a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am attempting to create a `UICollectionView` which is horizontal scrolling and a single row. Cells can be added dynamically to the end of the collection. I want the behaviour to be that when a certain number of cells are in the `UICollectionView` and a new one is added, the first `x` number of cells will squish their spacing whilst remaining the same size. Ideally I want the first `x` cells to actually overlap each other somewhat (would look like a stack) to conserve maximum space. The remaining cells in the collection after `x` will display with the normal spacing between them.

A visual:

`( ) ( ) ( ) ( ) ( )` normal layout where `( )` is an item

would become as such when two more items are added:

`((((( ) ( ) ( )`

or `( ))))) ( ) ( )` if the first item was at the top of the stack (I don't mind which right now, just the stack is important)

Can anyone offer any help and advice on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, I achieved this by subclassing `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and overriding as below. Bare in mind I used an additional cell at the end of the collection as an `addCell` button, so this implementation accounts for that and will do the rearrangement after 5 real items have been added and you go to add a 6th. My cells had a width of `50` with a minimum spacing of `10` when normally laid out.

```
override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    guard collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) > 6 else {
        return super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
    }

    let layouts = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)?.map { $0.copy() as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes }
    for (index, layout) in layouts!.enumerated() {
        var frame = layout.frame
        frame.origin.x = frame.origin.x - (35.0 * CGFloat(index < 5 ? index : (index - (index - 4))))
        layout.frame = frame
    }

    return layouts
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve any positioning you like, because you get to write the UICollectionViewLayout that tells the collection view how to position its items.

A flow layout, by default, will not do what you are describing. It simply lays out all the items in each row with the same spacing, based on the collection view content width and the minimum item spacing you supply. But if you *subclass* UICollectionViewFlowLayout, you can probably *modify* the behavior of the flow layout to do what you are describing. Thus, you would not need to write the layout object entirely from scratch.

However, for maximum flexibility, writing the layout object entirely from scratch is exactly what you would do. It really isn't all that hard. Apple has many examples and of course there are many tutorial examples out there as well.

Comment: Thanks, I took your advice in hand and found a solution through a combination of other SO answers to roughly related questions and the Apple docs

Comment: Yes, once you think about it from the point of view of subclassing UICollectionViewFlowLayout the technique is pretty standard. You are copying the `super` result and modifying that and returning it, which is exactly right.